# How to specify a SEO friendly url like twitter www.twitter.com/<name> using YII framework

Tags: php, seo, friendly-url, yii

I am currently using the Yii framework, and I would like to know if anyone has any clue on how to setup a SEO friendly url like www.twitter.com/ automatically in Yii? I know how to do so this manually in the config/main.php but I would like to be able to dynamically generate it. I have been able to do it in Grails as well. In Yii, what I know of is that you need to have another parameter like www.twitter.com/l/, but I do not want that parameter, anyone can share?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the config file main.php with this

```
'components'=>array(

            .....

            'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),

            ....
```

I think it is generated when you create a webapp with yiic-tool

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to achieve what you want by using the [URL Manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/topics.url)? If not, can you post an example of what you have currently and what you'd like it to be?

Comment: Oops, I answered my own question, yes, it can be done...
using the following direct pattern:
'<title:\w+>'=>'organization/viewtitle',

thanks.

Comment: Any change of either accepting my answer, or answering the question yourself (using an answer rather than a comment)?

Comment: There's a good step by step guide in the Yii Cookbook. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/cookbook/53/