# Controlling url in Yii: controller/action/id to /id

Tags: url, yii

Can we display url in the format `controller/action/id` to `/id` in Yii? Also, one major problem is that I need to do this only on the specific controller/action.

For Instance: If I have `/user/post/ujjwal` then I need to show `/ujjwal` only. And when I have `/image/display/ujjwal` then it can be as it is?

I have read the url management in Yii and understand whatever is shown in there. But I dont' know how to control the url based on the `controller/action`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ujjwal

Comment: you commented on one of the links that yii documentation was not the answer to your problem. Please post the excerpt from your config file relating to the url formatting.

Comment: what I meant was I could not find the possible near solution to my problem.. or may be I did not understand it so well that I could not relate it to my problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config/main.php` try

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
                        'rules'=>array(
                          'user/post/<user:\w+>'=>'<user>', //this should be the very first rule
                           //other rules 
                         ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: This is the other way around - the client-facing URI comes first in the array, then the controller/action pair. Also, putting the most general rule at the top will ensure that none of the other rules are ever reached.

Comment: I think your confusing the word specific with general. `user/post/<user:\w+>`will only match the `user` controller's `post` action when it has a word parameter.

Comment: Yes but OP doesn't want to access the /user/post action that way - he only wants the parameter name to be in the URL.

Comment: Yes, I just want username to map to user/profile/username and as suggested by aslingga, it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help guys!!

Comment: Hmmm... how come this answer did not get accepted, anyways i wanted to do something like @UjjwalPrajapati for a specific url only and this way of specifying rule did the trick... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you can not map one customized URL to two or more URL path or action. Like when someone access `/my_username` the will be redirected to `/user/post/ujjwal` or `/image/display/ujjwal`. The application will be confused because of this pattern/rules.

So I recommend you to change the `/image/display/ujjwal` to another pattern/rules. Like `/my_username/image`

I use `username` as the query string for selected username.

```
'components'=>array(

            .....

            'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<username:[\w.]+>'=>'user/post',
                '<username:[\w.]+>/display'=>'image/display',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),

            ....
```

Someone has asked this similar question before: [How to specify a SEO friendly url like twitter www.twitter.com/<name> using YII framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781882/how-to-specify-a-seo-friendly-url-like-twitter-www-twitter-com-name-using-yii)

Comment: Thank you. This is quite helpful and I followed your instruction. It works!!

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done, with a few side effects however. If you put this in your `config/main.php`:

```
        'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            'image/<action>/<username>' => 'image/action/username',
            '<username>' => 'user/post/username',
            ),
        ),
```

Put all your more specific rules first, then everything else that is a single unit will go to `/user/post/something`.