# Yii URL Custom Rule

Tags: url, yii

I'm having a lot of difficulties (more than I should anyway) to add a custom url rule.
My situation is as follows:

my site is hosted on `domain.com`
I want to redirect `games.domain.com/ID` to `domain.com/games/index/id`.

At this moment `games.domain.com` points to `domain.com`
I would like anything that starts with redirect. in the url to point to `domain.com/games/index/id/IDHERE`

Any tips/suggestions/help?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908931/controlling-url-in-yii-controller-action-id-to-id

Might be helpful for your situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
'http://games.domain.com/<id:.+>' => 'games/index/id/<id>',
```

Comment: and how to wildcard the domain?

Comment: What options you want there to be allowed?

Comment: what I am looking for is that every url looking like http://games.*/ID is redirected to games/index/id/ID

Comment: Well check out if works if you add there another variable `<domain:.+>`