# yii : how to config SEO friendly url at Yii?

Tags: yii, seo

I create a app by yiic. and then I tried to make a SEO url. I uncomment urlManager at [app root]/protected/config/main.php . And I add following into [app root]/.htaccess.

> RewriteEngine on
>
> ## if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> ## otherwise forward it to index.php
>
> RewriteRule . index.php

When I browse [app]/site/index, I got the error 404 - object not found. But if I browse by [app]/index.php?r=site/index, it is show me my app page. I followed many web sites by googling. but I got same error.

please help me to solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try to use this :

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Instead of using .htaccess you can use urlManager in Yii to have custom url rules. Take a read at urlManager for details. I hope this post might also help to give you the idea. [Controlling url in Yii: controller/action/id to /id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908931/controlling-url-in-yii-controller-action-id-to-id)

Comment: Ujjwal Prajapati, thank for your help. but I've no luck. same 404 error. I've more than 100 controller. I can't manage them manually. how can I solve?

Comment: Ok. Remove the htaccess for now to get rid of 404. Can you specify how exactly the url rules you want? I mean, what do you want in case of controller and no controller. or what you could do is have index.php/controller which will take you to controller page and index.php/staticontroller/post which will take you to one static controller to handle post with no controller. Will that do?

Comment: Now it is working as app/index.php/controller/action. How can I do like this app/controller/action.

Comment: to hide index.php, you have to use .htaccess. In your system check which url rules works. Yours right too as well as mine. And yes, you have to set showScriptName => false in urlManager.

Comment: 'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'showScriptName' => false,  
   'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
   ),

  ),
This is my urlManager. I setup .htaccess as your. how can I do like this app/controller/action?

Comment: So, are you getting some sorts of error because of .htaccess or you are not been able to get your desired url? What is the url that you getting now using these rules?

Comment: I didn't get an error of .htaccess. I checked at apache->error.log. Yes of course, I didn't get my desired url. This is current working url style app/index.php/controller/action. I want like this url style  app/controller/action. how can I?

Comment: The problem is with htaccess. Try the rewrite rules as mentioned here as well. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself.
1. uncomment urlManager at app/protected/config/main.php
2. create .htaccess file under app/ folder. (Important : not under app/protected/ folder)
3. copy and past the following code into new .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

That all. Thank you for your helping me, everybody.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this article on URL rewriting in Yii](http://yiitutorials.net/easy/easy-url-rewriting-with-yii)

Also, in your config, set showScriptName to false

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    ...
```